# Formula for How many combinations we can have from two sets with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Find the formula:

Let $A=\{1,2,...,27\}$ and $B=\{28,29, ...,50\}$.

How many combinations we can have from two sets: A and B; such that to obtain subsets of 7 elements, where 5 elements belongs to A and 2 to B, with restrictions that $2$ elements (pair) in one resulted subset should not repeat in other resulted subset.

How to find the formula such way that I can use restrictions variables as parameters for this formula. By restriction variables I mean those $5$ elements from $A$ and $2$ from $B$, and limit of $2$ elements that should not repeat in subsets results.

I suppose that the first thing I should do is to find all the possible combinations without restrictions, which will represent the biggest set. Then I should find subsets from biggest set which matches separate restriction. And finally, exclude subsets from biggest set. So that we can find the total amount of combinations we look for.

If this is true, then I should calculate Combinations from $N$ elements = $A$ Length, grouped by $5$.

For example:

{1,2,3,4,5,6,28} and {1,2,3,4,5,7,28} violates the restriction because the pair {1,2} repeats. Other example is {1,2,3,4,5,6,28} and {1,2,6,7,8,9,29} also violates the restriction because {1,2} repeats.

Please help, to find how to achieve this, as I'm not sure.

Comment: The sets $A,B$ do not intersect, so the condition on "repeats" doesn't appear to matter here.  There are $\binom {27}5$ ways to choose $5$ elements from $A$ and $\binom {23}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ elements from $B$, and then you can just multiply to get your result.  Or have I not understood the restriction?

Comment: @lulu {1,2,3,4,5,6,28} and {1,2,3,4,5,7,28} violates the restriction because the pair {1,2} repeats. Other example is {1,2,3,4,5,6,28} and {1,2,6,7,8,9,29} also violates the restriction because {1,2} repeats.

Comment: I don't understand.  Please edit your post for clarity.

Comment: Are $\{1,2,3,4,5,28,29\}$ and $\{1,6,7,8,9,28,30\}$ allowed together?  They share $1$ and $28$, but those are not both from $A$ nor $B$.  Note your examples above just have one element from $B$.

Comment: @Ross your example also violates the restriction, because we have the repeating pair {1,28}

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: There are people who do this kind of combinatorics who can probably at least suggest the search terms to use.  I suspect you have to decide whether to have disjoint subsets from $A$ and subsets that may share one element from $B$ or the other way around.  I would then guess you want the subsets from $A$ to share an element.  You can get $11$ pairwise disjoint subsets from $B$ that you can combine with all the subsets from $A$.  I don't know how to find the largest family from $A$ that has single pairwise intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can solve this as a set packing problem.  For $S\subset \{1,\dots,50\}$ with $|S \cap A|=5$ and $|S \cap B|=2$, let binary variable $x_S$ indicate whether set $S$ is selected.  The problem is to maximize $\sum_S x_S$ subject to:
$$\sum_{S: \{i,j\} \subset S} x_S \le 1 \quad \text{for $1\le i<j\le 50$}$$

Comment: Your answer looks like a better description for my problem conditions. It says more what we should do, than how to do, because I need to find the number of combinations we can have using some restrictions. Thank you for your answer, I would vote up your answer because it is relevant but this is not allowed at the moment.